# What is the difference between my own php post and the post from Google Chrome Advanced Rest Client?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to call a php in my website to login to another side. Here is my code:

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://another.web.com/login.do';
$data = array('loginname' => 'username', 
    'password' => 'password', 
    'act' => 'ajaxLogin2Json', 
    'app' => 'oauth2', 
    'callback' => 'login_callback' );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                        ));     
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mytest');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

It shows me login successfully. But when I goto the website it still shows I'm not logined.

But when I'm using the Google Chrome's Advanced Rest Client App to login with the same parameter.

[image]

It shows me the same result as I did with my php code. But it shows me logined when I goto the website (another.web.com). I'm wondering what is the difference between my php code and the Advanced Rest Client? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about cookies.
Advanced Rest Client App use cookies of your browser. But PHP Curl is not.

Comment: This is what I guessed. My question is if it's possible to use the cookie in my PHP curl code? Thanks

Comment: @bagusflyer you can not set cookie for another domain so you can not use cookies from PHP CUrl for your browser. Solution : using javascript to submit login form to website that you want to login.